# Как мне убрать невидимую линию(я не знаю как она называется

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне это нужно чтобы расположить слоган под заголовком
Вот код: html:

```css
body {
  background-color: #5c636a;
}

.Day {
  width: 375px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 20%;
  margin-left: 770px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

.hat {
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #4d5154;
  display: flex;
}

.text {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.h11 {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 850px;
}

.p1 {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-right: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-aFq/bzH65dt+w6FI2ooMVUpc+21e0SRygnTpmBvdBgSdnuTN7QbdgL+OapgHtvPp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hat">
    <p>
      <h1 class="text h11">RusWeather</h1>
      <h3 class="text p1">Самый лучший сервис для просмотра погоды</h3>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Никакая то ни невидимая линия. Добавьте к `h1` и `h3` `outline: 1px dashed red;`, это покажет высоту и ширину блоков, так вы наглядно увидите что у вас `h1` занимает почти всю высоту `.hat`'а.

Answer (score 0):

если прям не заморачиваться то

```css
.hat {
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #4d5154;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="hat">
  <h1 class="text h11">RusWeather</h1>
  <h3 class="text p1">Самый лучший сервис для просмотра погоды</h3>
</div>
```

и марджины убери